# Flip image with front camera on ARKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

I'm switching between the front and back cameras in RealityKit using SwiftUI. However, when using the front camera, I encountered an issue where the captured image appears mirrored.

I think it's causing the app to be unable to detect the image I added in 'AR Resources' under Assets.

**How can I flip that image?**

You can refer to `func switchCamera()` and the captured image below:

```
func switchCamera() {
    
    print("DEBUGG: switchCamera on Model")
    guard var newConfig = arView.session.configuration else {
        return
    }
    
    switch newConfig {
    case is ARWorldTrackingConfiguration:
        newConfig = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
    case is ARFaceTrackingConfiguration:
        newConfig = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    default:
        newConfig = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    }
    arView.session.run(newConfig)
}
```

Captured image:

[image]

---

***Update Solution - I found a simple solution to my question***

By specifying the transform applied to the view with two lines of code, I can achieve the desired effect:

- For the front camera, I will use the following of code:

  `arView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)`
- For the rear camera, I will use:

  `arView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)`

With these changes, my code will modified as follows:

```
func switchCamera() {
    
    print("DEBUGG: switchCamera on Model")
    guard var newConfig = arView.session.configuration else {
        return
    }
    
    switch newConfig {
    case is ARWorldTrackingConfiguration:
        newConfig = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        arView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1) // Add here
    case is ARFaceTrackingConfiguration:
        newConfig = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        arView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1) // Add here
    default:
        newConfig = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    }
    arView.session.run(newConfig)
}
```

The solution works well for both rear and front cameras:

[image]

Comment: idk how is this related to swiftui

Comment: A "Switch Camera" button using swiftUI will use the `func switchCamera()` @mrpaw69

Answer (score 1):

You can flip your image using Apple's built-in `CoreImage` framework.

1. You need to create a `CIImage` from a `CVPixelBuffer`(extracted from frame)
2. Apply transform to created CIImage
3. Convert it back to CVPixelBuffer(or something else, based on your needs)

```swift
func flipImage(buffer: CVPixelBuffer) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
    // 1
    var ci = CIImage(pixelBuffer: buffer)
    // 2
    // scale image by -1 x, making it mirrored horizontally
    ci = ci.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
    // image is moved to the left, so we need to put it back
    ci = ci.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(translationX: ci.extent.width, y: 0))

    // 3
    // creating a CIContext with Metal device for rendering to new cvpixelbuffer on GPU (making it faster)
    guard let mtlDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else { return nil }
    // creating new buffer
    guard let newBuffer = createPixelBuffer(width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(buffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(buffer), pixelFormat: CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(buffer))
    // creating context
    let context = CIContext(mtlDevice: mtlDevice)
    // rendering our flipped ci to newBuffer
    context.render(ci, to: newBuffer)
    return newBuffer
}
```

Then call this function in your photo handling function(possible approach)

```swift
// get your buffer and cam data
var buffer = <your buffer>
let isFront = <is front camera?>
if isFront {
    // flip
    buffer = flipImage(buffer: buffer) ?? buffer // if it fails fallback to original
}
// handle your buffer
```

Helper function to create an empty pixelbuffer from CoreMLHelpers

```swift
fileprivate func metalCompatiblityAttributes() -> [String: Any] {
    let attributes: [String: Any] = [
        String(kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey): true,
        String(kCVPixelBufferOpenGLCompatibilityKey): true,
        String(kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey): [
            String(kCVPixelBufferIOSurfaceOpenGLESTextureCompatibilityKey): true,
            String(kCVPixelBufferIOSurfaceOpenGLESFBOCompatibilityKey): true,
            String(kCVPixelBufferIOSurfaceCoreAnimationCompatibilityKey): true
        ]
    ]
    return attributes
}

func createPixelBuffer(width: Int, height: Int, pixelFormat: OSType) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
    let attributes = metalCompatiblityAttributes() as CFDictionary
    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
    let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(nil, width, height, pixelFormat, attributes, &pixelBuffer)
    if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
        print("Error: could not create pixel buffer", status)
        return nil
    }
    return pixelBuffer
}
```

Comment: I found a simple solution base on your code. Thanks a lot, @mrpaw69